# Obtener nombre SP ejecutado C# SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server

Consulta,
hay alguna forma de obtener el nombre del procedimiento almacenado al ejecutarlo, y almacenarlo en una variable para luego mostrarla. Tengo un dataset creado con el asistente de origenes de datos de Visual Studio y que contiene el SP que ejecuto y el cual deseo capturar el nombre del SP.

Codigo de como asigno el dataset ya creado en el asistente de origenes de datos.

```
 this.sBO_VAR_REP_VEN_VentasTotales_VZ_MC_EX_CAJTableAdapter.Fill
(this.ds_rptCajMCE.SBO_VAR_REP_VEN_VentasTotales_VZ_MC_EX_CAJ,_periodo, _desde, _hasta);

                    rptCajMCE reporte = new rptCajMCE();
                    reporte.SetDataSource(ds_rptCajMCE);

                    reporte.SetParameterValue("PERI", _periodo);
                    reporte.SetParameterValue("FecIni", _desde);
                    reporte.SetParameterValue("FecFin", _hasta);
                    this.crvReporteMCE.ReportSource = reporte;
                    this.crvReporteMCE.Zoom(1);
```

Comment: que retorna tu procedimiento? intenta retornar el nombre del sp desde el mismo procedimiento.

Comment: ¿Pero si lo estás ejecutando no tienes ya el nombre?

Comment: solo retorna la data que necesito, habría forma sin modificar el SP.@ErickCastillo

Comment: @PatricioMoracho, no lo tengo declarado ni instanciado el dataset se creo con el asistente y solo lo llamo al ejecutar el reporte.

Comment: @R.segura , has que tu sp retorne una segunda tabla con el nombre del SP, luego en c# obtienes el dato de la tabla 1. deberías mostrar parte del código para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: Estas en windows form y usando los sqldatasource con asistente?

Comment: @ErickCastillo, si uso windows form

Comment: " el dataset se creo con el asistente y solo lo llamo al ejecutar el reporte." y entonces agrega una variable con el nombre... o nos estamos perdiendo algo?

Comment: @gbianchi pensé en esa opción pero quería saber si hay otra, con algún método o función predefinida del dataset que me obtenga el nombre del SP

Comment: Pero si lo sabes de antemano, que ganas escribiendo un procedimiento que te va a devolver lo que ya sabes?